# Struct C++ array in function parameters not working at all

Tags: c++, arrays, function, struct, structure

hello i have to do a program using an array of structures.. and i have to initialize it in a function. below i am trying, but my prototype keeps getting error "Expected primary expression".. i have followed tutorials but  cant figure out what im doing wrong please help. i cant use pointers or vectors.. just basic stuff thank you for your time

```
struct gameCases{

bool flag = false;
int casenum;
double value;
};
 int initialize(gameCases cases);  //prototype
```

--- main()

```
gameCases cases[26];
initialize(cases);    //call
```

---

```
int initialize(gameCases cases)  //definition
{
double values[26] = {.01, 1, 5, 10, 25, 50,
                75, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 750, 1000,
                5000, 10000 , 25000, 50000, 75000, 100000,
                200000 , 300000, 400000, 500000,
                1000000, 2000000};

for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
{
    array[i].value = values[i];
}
}
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int initialize(gameCases cases[26]);  //prototype

int initialize(gameCases cases[26])  //definition
{
    double values[26] = {.01, 1, 5, 10, 25, 50,
            75, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 750, 1000,
            5000, 10000 , 25000, 50000, 75000, 100000,
            200000 , 300000, 400000, 500000,
            1000000, 2000000};

    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        cases[i].value = values[i];
    }
}
```

and to call:

```
initialize(cases);
```

Comment: is call ...   initialize(cases[])   ??

Comment: updated my post. But really, the first solution given by Vlad from Moscow is the better one.

Comment: in your case with your restrictions yes, in real life no

Answer (score 1):

Declare the function like

```
int initialize( gameCases *array, size_t n );
```

and call it like

```
initialize( cases, 26 );
```

Or you could pass the array by reference. For example

```
int initialize( gameCases ( &cases )[26] );
```

Take into account that the function is declared as having return type int but it acrually returns nothing.

Comment: thank you but the post says no pointers.  can you devise a way to do this without pointers, Vlad?

Comment: @user3349184 You marked the post as best where the function parameter is a pointer though you said that a pointer shall not be used.:) This declaration gameCases cases[26] is equivalent to gameCases *cases The only correct solution is to use reference as I showed.